# Not able to run UFT 14.50 scripts on MS Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, ui-automation, hp-uft, uft14

There is a requirement for running UFT scripts on MS Edge as IE 11 is going to retire soon. I have tried copying MS Edge driver files to UFT Installation bin folder but its not working. I am able to launch the MS Edge browser but nothing happens afterward. UFT is not interacting with MS Edge browser and its elements.

Comment: What version of Edge are you currently using? Does it work in Chrome? Or you can try it in [Edge Canary](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/canary). If possible, can you provide more relevant details to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I have tried both UFT 14.50 and 14.53 and both behave the same way with MS Edge 96.0.1054.57 and Chrome 97.0.4692.99on Windows 10 64 bit machine